# prove that sides of orthic triangle meet the sides of the given triangle in 3 colinear points

Tags: geometry, triangles

$ABC$ is a triangle and $EFG$ is its orthic triangle. prove that sides of orthic triangle meet the sides of the triangle $ABC$ in 3 colinear points.

[image]

i drew the following figure..i just need an approach or a hint.

thankyou!

Comment: This follows directly from the definition of an orthic triangle.

Comment: pl elaborate @Mick

Comment: The vertices of the orthic triangle are the feet of the altitudes of the original triangle. These feet will land on the sides of the original triangle. The sides of the orthic triangle are formed by joining these vertices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This actually follows directly from Desargue's theorem:

Given two arbitrary triangles $ABC$ and $EFG$, the lines $AG, \, BE$ and $CE$ are concurrent if and only if the three intersection points $R = CA \cap FG, \,  S = BC \cap EF$ and $T = AB \cap GE$ are collinear.

Comment: ok. i get it...

Comment: Can we prove it by using the information that the triangle is orthic?

Comment: What methods are you supposed to use or what methods do you use in class? What is the current topic you have been discussing in class?

Comment: i study on my own, from higher mathematics books. and am only aware of euclidean geometry.